# JPA Repository method inside of mocked Service Class returns null

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

I have a service method that looks like this

```
@Override
public User editUser(User user) {

    User savedUser = userRepository.findById(user.getUser_id()).get();
    User userToEdit = new User();

    userToEdit.setUser_id(user.getUser_id());
    userToEdit.setRole(user.getRole().isEmpty() ? savedUser.getRole() : user.getRole());
    userToEdit.setUsername(user.getUsername().isEmpty() ? savedUser.getUsername() : user.getUsername());
    userToEdit.setPassword(user.getPassword().isEmpty() ? savedUser.getPassword() : passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    userToEdit.setEmail(user.getEmail().isEmpty() ? savedUser.getEmail() : user.getEmail());
    userToEdit.setGroup_id((user.getGroup_id() == -1) ? savedUser.getGroup_id() : user.getGroup_id());
    userToEdit.setActive(user.getActive()!=savedUser.getActive() ? savedUser.getActive() : user.getActive());

    return userRepository.save(userToEdit);
}
```

And I'm trying to test it with Mockito and when I call a repository method in the service class while testing it return a empty Optional

Here's my before each test method

```
@BeforeEach
public void setup(){
    user = new User(1,"username", "password", 1, "test@test.com", "admin", true);
}
```

and my test method

```
@Test
void checkIfUserCanBeEdited(){

    given(userRepository.save(user)).willReturn(user);
    user.setPassword("check");
    user.setRole("user");

    //when
    User updateUser = userService.editUser(user);

    //then
    assertThat(updateUser.getPassword()).isEqualTo("check");
    assertThat(updateUser.getRole()).isEqualTo("user");
}
```

And the error

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
```

at this line

```
User savedUser = userRepository.findById(user.getUser_id()).get();
```

Comment: is your test class marked `@SpringBootTest`? Can you show the class-level code?

Comment: since `userService` calls two `userRepository` methods: `save` and `findById`, you need to mock both of them.

Comment: @Ryednap it's only marked with ```@Slf4j``` and ```@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)```

Comment: Where do you create your mock and how do you inject it into your service? Can you sholl the full test class? (including annotations, fields, setup code). The single test method is enough, the others can be removed for the question

Comment: You don't need to use `@SpringBootTest` for this -- just using `MockitoExtension` is sufficient and better.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare that behaviour to the mock, before using it:

```java
when(userRepository.findById(any()))
   .thenReturn(Optional.empty());
```

Comment: `editUser` expects that the user always exists.

Comment: Then return Optional.of(testUser) and create testUser upfront.